Closed loop Hall current sensor, is it possible to shift the result from negative output?
I am planning to use this closed loop Hall current sensor.

Is it possible to use a unipolar power supply (ie. only +24V, no negative) and shift the result by not connecting RM to ground, but to a positive reference?
It appears that the chip doesn't need a bipolar supply for itself, just to swing to the negative region.
I'd like to shift like 300mV, get the entire +/- range into positive with offset.

Yes, that should work in general. The unit has no ground connection at all, so it won't know.
I'm not at all optimistic about your 300mV though. You probably need a few volts since the internal amplifier won't be able to swing close to the rails.
Also the minimum supply voltage is specified as 28.6V (48V typical), and you're proposing giving it only 24.

hmm.. I miss that part 24V :)) seems that I have to use a dual supply anyhow.
